# Import profile picture from Twitter

Tags: python, url, twitter, jpeg, tweepy

I need help! I'm trying to import a profile picture (.jpg) from Twitter with Jupyter and Tweepy, but I do not know which code should I use? I made a request but I only obtain the link .url of the profile picture?
Thank you in advance!

```
from IPython.display import Image 
for le_tweet in tweets_menacants : 
   print("Image du profil de", le_tweet.user.screen_name, ":") 
   print (le_tweet.user.profile_image_url) 
   Image(url = le_tweet.user.profile_image_url)
```

Comment: Please post your code as text rather than an image so that it is easier to copy-paste it and test it out for ourselves.

Comment: Please include your code as part of the question.